# FluentValidation provide full path to property

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

When performing validation on an API request, the resource structure can be quite nested:

```
public class NewAccountRequest
{
    public AccountInfo Account { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class AccountInfo
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public PersonalDetails PersonalDetails { get; set; }
}

public class PersonalDetails
{
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set;}
}
```

When the user sends this to my controller, I want to validate it using FluentValidation to make sure all the preconditions are met. In the response, I want to return error information to include the full path to the element which has failed validation.

If I create a validator for each of these object types the values returned in the validation errors includes only the property names:

```
public class NewAccountRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<NewAccountRequest>
{
    public NewAccountRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(request => request.Account)
            .SetValidator(new AccountInfoValidator())
            .NotNull();

        RuleFor(request => request.Username)
            .NotNull();

        RuleFor(request => request.Password)
            .NotNull();
    }
}

public class AccountInfoValidator : AbstractValidator<AccountInfo>
{
    public AccountInfoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(account => account.Email)
            .NotNull();
    }
}
```

When the account info doesn't specify an email address, it will use "Email" as the property name. I would like to return "Account.Email".

If I stop using a nested validator, and specify the full path to all the properties in the root object validator, the result is given as "Account Email" which I can convert into the camel-cased version I want for my API. I would like this same behaviour when using nested validators, so I don't have a gigantic validator class for my request objects.

Comment: Add a constructor that passes the root (parent) path, and if set, you prefix it to the property name

Comment: @KevinCook Could you elaborate how? Perhaps an answer with some code?

Comment: Look for RootContext in the fluentvalidation api.